# How does Vilgax survive in outer space?

Tags: ben-10

I have never seen Vilgax in Space Suit when he appear in outer space. In movie *Ben 10 and Secret of the Omnitrix*, he appeared in vacuum multiple times.

Assuming he is a powerful creature whose body can ignore pressure difference between vacuum and atmosphere (even laser blasters don't affect his body), how can he live without oxygen or something similar for respiration? I have seen gazillions of Sci-Fi canons, but never found a single living organism which could live without respiration.

Is there any information of his species regarding this? How does his body produce energy without respiration?

Answer (score 2):

Within the first season ( and I think first episode ) of the original show, it is shown that a majority of his body was destroyed and he spends a fair amount of time in a reconstruction pod of some sort. In theory he could have greatly augmented his body to reduce any possible weaknesses and may only be "breathing" for dramatic effect when he may not actually need air.

Comment: Do you have any citation of your last sentence?

Comment: There is no citation because it is just a potential theory. I'm not sure you are going to get an actual citation for this since I don't think there is a canon answer.

Answer (score -1):

The man wears a mask so it could, theoretically, be connected to a pressurized air container. We've seen how strong he is so I'm willing the bet his skin is strong enough to handle the vacuum of space (like a [tardigrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade))

Comment: This seems very speculative to me.

Comment: @Valorum it's never outright said why in the show so speculation is the only thing we have

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't make for a great answer, especially if you need to add in things that aren't seen in the show to make your answer make sense.

Comment: @Valorum then why would he wear a breathing mask if it wasn't connected to an air tank, also im only adding an air tank based on logic, nothing else, I don't see you answering this buddy

Comment: An invisible air tank? Why not just have an entire invisible spacesuit?

Comment: @Valorum never said that